# how to mount a writable loopback image as easily as we can create it?

Tags: disk-image, loop-device

To create a image we just run `gnome-disks` and then format it. And the 1st time it will be (auto?) mounted writable.

but after that, I can only mount it readonly with the "open with disk image mounter" on nemo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [gnome-disk-image-mounter](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gnome-disk-image-mounter.1.html) application. Try to find it using
`grep Exec /usr/share/applications/gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop`

You can use
`gnome-disk-image-mounter URI`
Where **URI** is the name of your disk image file. But you can't write on this.

If you want to write use writable option:
`gnome-disk-image-mounter -w URI`