# How to read and write inside mounted vendor.img

Tags: mount, gnome-terminal, android, filemanager, read-only

I need help with editing vendor.img.

I had a problem where if I mounted vendor.img, it's just read-only, I tried to edit permission via file manager's properties tab, but that don't work. Is there any command I can do on terminal so I can read and write not just read the vendor.img?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to mount containers.Old but the commands are still the same: https://askubuntu.com/a/175742/15811  More recent https://askubuntu.com/a/1366757/15811  using `gnome-disk-image-mounter -w {file.img}`

Comment: I did that, and it is mounted, but it's still read only.